# How do I spoof an HTTP request to test a .NET Web Service

Tags: web-services, debugging, httprequest, spoofing

I have a web service that is running on a test instance in IIS. Unfortunately, certain requests to it cause it to throw basic errors like "Object not set to an instance of an object".

The people who use the webservice then send me the full HTTP request (including headers) that caused the error, which I now need to throw at the instance running in my development environment to bug fix.

Any suggestions on how to do this? (Putty would work but you cant copy and paste into Putty when its connected and that makes for laborious debugging!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody posted **Fiddler** http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ on this answer earlier and then deleted it - I gave it a try and it works fantastically. (thanks)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.soapui.org/

SOAP UI is a nice soft for this kind of things, you can add your reference, and then copy/paste your friends request !

To add your reference :

Launch SoapUI

- Right Click on "Projects"
- New SoapUI Project
- Fill the "Initial WSDL" textbox with your local wsdl url (ie "http://localhost:1234webservice.asmx?wsdl" (don't forget ?wsdl))
- Click "OK"

To execute your request

- Expand your newly created project
- Expand the port you whish to use (the main difference is the wsdm version 1.1 or 1.2)
- Right click on your Method
- "New request"
- On the Request windows copy /paste that you received
- Click on the green triangle on the top right corner of this window.

Comment: Hmmm, I feel dumb! May I ask how you would go about this in SoapUI? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use soap UI. http://www.soapui.org/